# using facebook oauth with Rest Server

Tags: social-network, theming, 8, authentication-authorization

I'm building an Android app that communicates with Drupal Services 3 through Rest Server module.
On Drupal side, I'm using Facebook oAuth module for authentication.
so I want to let the app users login through their facebook account and issue authenticated rest requests to Drupal.

How is that possible, and is there any detailed guides?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the way is to use Android FB API to make the user register and send the info to REST server.

Comment: You will need to create a new services login resource and hook it to the `Facebook oAuth` module

Comment: @drcleus can you clarify more dear